# How to show or hide a div on hover of kendo-menu-item in angular 8

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, dom

I want to hide a div element on hover of kendo-menu-item in angular 8.
I want to hide  a div whose class is "nav-flyout" on hover of kendo-menu-item "what we do"

Here is the html code

```
<div class="toolbar navbar" role="banner">
  <span><h3>My Project</h3></span>
  <div class="spacer"></div>
  <kendo-menu class="navbar">
    <kendo-menu-item
      [cssClass]="'what-we-do'"
      text="What We Do"
      url="/whatwedo"
    ></kendo-menu-item>
    <kendo-menu-item text="Our Team" url="/ourteam"></kendo-menu-item>
    <kendo-menu-item text="Our Work" url="/ourwork"></kendo-menu-item>
    <kendo-menu-item text="Resources" url="/resources"></kendo-menu-item>
    <kendo-menu-item text="Who Are We" url="/whoarewe"></kendo-menu-item>
  </kendo-menu>
  <button kendoButton [primary]="true">Let's Talk</button>
  <div id="rightSpace"></div>
</div>
<div class="content" role="main"></div>
<div class="mega-nav-contain project-container">
  <div id="what-we-do-flyout" class="nav-flyout">
    <div class="row-fluid center">
      <div class="span4">
        <h3 class="loop-title">
          <a href="">
            <span class="green">Website</span> Design</a>
        </h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `mouse-event`in `kendo-menu-item` like:

```
<kendo-menu-item (mouseover)="yourFun()" text="Our Team" url="/ourteam"></kendo-menu-item>
```

and in this function `yourFun()` change `display-style` , Triggers when cursor is over the [mouseover](https://dev.to/orahul1/angular-mouse-events-41l9) applied element (like hover).

Comment: I tried using mouseover event. But it is not working.